# Use an angular service which is not injected anywhere

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-dependency-injection

Suppose you have an Angular service (`ZombieService`) which, for example, monitors an other service.
And, `ZombieService` isn't injected anywhere [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xg43qm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

The problem is that, when you do not inject a service anywhere, that service is completely ignored (not executed). The solution is to inject it into, for example, AppComponent

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ './app.component.scss' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
    constructor(zombieService: ZombieService) {}
    ...
}
```

Although this works, I was wondering if there isn't a better solution for this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you precise what you mean by "stripped out" ? Maybe you can precise what you are trying to do.

Comment: If you do not inject a service, it will not be executed. So, if you have a service running some kind of background task, you have to inject it somehwere

Comment: nope, this is how you do it.

Comment: You need static methods if you dont want inject the service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is that, when you do not inject a service anywhere, that
>   service is completely ignored (not executed).

Because a file which is not referred by any others, is as good as a file from different project. There is no point in initialising a service which has no reference.

**Only the files referred from main entry file(s) are considered for creating bundling by WebPack or any other JS orchestrating tool.**

These kinds of services are injected at `AppComponent`, or can also be at module-level component.

This is the most general case of tracking / analytics, and there's an initialisation step which needs to be done in service for most of them, which needs the service to be injected at some component (probably `AppComponent`).